# モデレーションでコメントの削除をする際は技術的な内容を残してほしい

Tags: 討議, モデレーション

次の質問で、回答に続いてコメントをしたが削除された。

- [StoryboardのNavigation Barの存在理由](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/12613/10678)

コメントの削除理由・修正の要請・削除することの事前または事後のメッセージ一切の告知はなく投稿者本人にとっては全くの秘密裏に行われた。結果コメントと合わせて機能していた追記部分の画像は意味不明なものとなった。

現在、質問者の

> （略）しかしNavigation BarにNavigation Itemを追加しようとしても追加できず使えません。。。使い方が間違っていると思うのですが、一般的にはどういう使い方をするのでしょうか？

という最初のコメントが残りこの疑問に技術的に答えていた俺のコメントは存在していない。記録が残っていないから回答に移すこともできないな。

---

これを行ったモデレーターは [tomute](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/33/tomute)、[unarist](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/8000/unarist) のどちらかだと思うが **コメントの問題部分のみを削除するか技術的な側面だけを回答本文に移す** こともできたんじゃないのか？今からでもそうできるならそうしてくれ。今後もそうすべきだと俺は思う。なぜこのようにせず丸ごと削除したのかできれば理由を聞かせてくれ。これは

[サイト モデレーターとは誰で、ここでの役割は何ですか?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

> モデレーターの操作の根拠に疑問がある場合は、メタで議論してください。

に従って質問させてもらってる。

Comment: モデレーターの過剰な編集がスタックオーバーフローのガンになってるような気はしますね

Comment: @プリン モデレーターだけが書き込みを削除できるわけではありません。[スパムまたは不快として通報するとどうなりますか?](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

失礼しました。削除したのは私です。
技術的に答えていたコメントを復活させました（不適切と思われる表現は一部修正してます）。
修正したのは「質問者に対して不必要に攻撃的になっている」と判断したからです。

Comment: 修正ありがとう。その理由はモデそのものの理由だと思うがここでの議題は **初動** で **技術的な内容ごと削除** したモデの質だ。現状のように修正可能だったはずがそうしなかった、その判断基準が要点なんだ。俺は質問文でも初めからこの部分を尋ねている。これはなぜだ？

Comment: @user10678 初動で技術的な内容ごと削除した理由ですが、既に承認された別の回答が存在しているので、該当コメントを削除してもコンテンツとしての価値は毀損されないと考えたからです（質問と承認済みの回答を見ることで、他のユーザの方が見ても十分に意味のある物になると判断）。ただ、ご指摘のように現状の形に修正可能でしたので、コメントの削除は安易であったと思います。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 「不適切と思われる表現のあるコメントを削除 → 指摘を受け、判断を改め、不適切表現を修正した上で技術的な内容部分を再公開」という対応に問題があるとは思えません。このサイトのガイドライン http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior には「常に礼節をもって行動してください。不作法は許されません」と書かれています。今回の「不適切と思われる表現」を礼節を欠いた一種の「不作法」と見れば、それは本来許されない行為ですから削除されたのは当然のことに思えます。技術的内容が書いてあれば不作法であっても削除されない、ということを保証するような公式文書は見当たりません。また同じく、削除される際にコメントと回答が良い具合に修正されるサービスを保証する表記も見当たりません。ガイドラインを守って通報や削除とならない適切なコメントを投稿するかどうか、そして、回答が回答単体で理解される内容であるかどうか、また、回答が分かりにくくなったと思われる場合に編集するかどうか、はすべて投稿者本人の自己責任の範囲ではないでしょうか。編集機能があることでサイトの質が向上する点は素晴らしいと思うのですが、どのような場合においても、修正や編集を義務化させる（または投稿者が他者の編集を当てにし過ぎる）ようなことは慣例となっていただきたくないので、一意見としてコメントさせていただきました。

Comment: @tomute 理由を教えてくれてありがとう。モデレーションに問題があったとするかどうかは個々人の判断だ。俺はこういうモデがあったという記録とその理由を明らかにできれば十分だ。コメントに対するモデは記録に残らないからな。